# iOS animation gets cancelled in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, caanimation

I have my own implementation of a `UIActivityView` in my app.

It is composed of two images that rotate in opposite directions. The view is created in `viewDidLoad` of a view controller and starts animating based off of an `NSNotification`.

When the view controller is first created and pushed onto the screen, the spinner displays itself, the code to start the animation executes, however the delegate method `-animationDidStop:finished:` is immediately called with `finished = NO`. This only happens on iOS 7. In iOS 6 the finished parameter is correctly "`YES`". Once the view controller is loaded the animation always works, it's just the first time where `finished = NO`.

Has anyone had a similar issue where animations are getting interrupted in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6 when a new view comes onto screen? Do you have any suggestions to debug this? I've already verified that everything is happening on the main thread and that the order in which things execute is the same between iOS 7 and iOS 6.